# Using toProvider in Google Guice

Tags: java, guice, provider

In Google Guice, we could do something like:

```
public class DSM extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure(){
bind(DSM.class).to(DSMI.class);
}
}
```

This will simply bind the DSM to a concrete implementation of the class.
But I have also seen code like:

```
bind(DSM.class).toProvider(()->DSM.create("")).in(Singleton.class);
```

My guess is that create must be a static method that must be returning an instance
of DSM class. Is this provider some kind of design pattern?
Not sure what does .in does here

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two questions.

**What is a provider?**

First, an provider is just a generic functional interface, witch should return an instance of the specified type.

For ex.:

```java
public class TestProvider implements Provider<Test> {

    @Override
    public Test get() {
        return new Test();
    }
}

Provider<Test> provider = new TestProvider();
```

or as a lamda:

```java
Provider<Test> provider = () -> new Test();
```

**How does a scope act with a provider?**

The .in() method call specifies the scope. In this case it is a singleton. So what happens behind the scenes is, that Guice creates an provider around your provider:

```java
public class ExampleSingletonProvider implements com.google.inject.Provider<Test> {

    private final Provider<Test> testProvider;
    private Test instance;

    public ExampleSingletonProvider(Provider<Test> testProvider) {
        this.testProvider = testProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public Test get() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = testProvider.get();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

This invokes the `Provider#get()` method once and caches its result.